# Uptime requires sudo password

Tags: sudo, access-control, uptime

I was wondering if anyone could give me some info on why does `uptime` keeps requiring sudo password? Indeed `uptime` runs without any sudo access from my trminal.

```
$ id -u; uptime
1000
 17:39:48 up  2:27,  1 user,  load average: 0.47, 0.46, 0.43
```

The above message comes from the logs if I type the following:

```
$ journalctl -xe -p4 -b0
Jul 06 17:40:25 tower sudo[6212]:     user : a password is required ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/uptime
```

I see a lot of the same error log entries in in each boot session:

```
$ journalctl -p 0..3 -b 0 /usr/bin/sudo | grep 'COMMAND=/usr/bin/uptime' | wc -l
23
```

My main concern is that I dunno what is causing this. It's homehow related to `uptime` but *I can easily run it through terminal without any sudo access*.

Related system info:

```
$ groups
klay adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev systemd-journal lpadmin sambashare
```

```
$ /usr/bin/uptime --version
uptime from procps-ng 3.3.12
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep -v '^$\|^#'
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

**Update:**
I was able to reproduce this.

1. Open two terminals as a regular user (`klay` in my case)
2. In terminal #1 run `journalctl -p 0..3 -b 0 /usr/bin/sudo -o json-pretty -f`
3. In terminal #2 run `uptime`
4. See in terminal #1 *new* log entry:

```
{
    "__CURSOR" : "s=7e0cb49d28c54b17af94118de422a9af;i=3c19;b=5ad166f483d6413993261193d918fb06;m=27afb71e0;t=58d049a09ba19;x=936d4267c2ff5ea9",
    "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1562425787267609",
    "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "10653233632",
    "_BOOT_ID" : "5ad166f483d6413993261193d918fb06",
    "_MACHINE_ID" : "19b1af3bdb99434abb76fe916804a0af",
    "_HOSTNAME" : "tower",
    "_UID" : "0",
    "_SELINUX_CONTEXT" : "unconfined\n",
    "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "3fffffffff",
    "_TRANSPORT" : "syslog",
    "SYSLOG_FACILITY" : "10",
    "_SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE" : "-.slice",
    "_GID" : "1000",
    "_AUDIT_LOGINUID" : "1000",
    "_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID" : "1000",
    "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "user@1000.service",
    "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "user-1000.slice",
    "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "sudo",
    "_COMM" : "sudo",
    "_EXE" : "/usr/bin/sudo",
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/gnome-terminal-server.service",
    "_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT" : "gnome-terminal-server.service",
    "_AUDIT_SESSION" : "5",
    "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID" : "feef60da3b1f42988bfa317c8abe736c",
    "PRIORITY" : "1",
    "MESSAGE" : "    klay : a password is required ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/klay ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/uptime",
    "_CMDLINE" : "sudo -n uptime",
    "_PID" : "9504",
    "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1562425787267574"
}
```

It is a fresh Ubuntu install. I have the same on a fresh Debian system.

Comment: It is not uptime that requires a password, but sudo. The `COMMAND` is the program that was (unnecessarily)  given to sudo to execute.

Comment: You have script or an user that keeps running uptime with sudo

Comment: @muru It is a fresh Ubuntu install. I have the same on a fresh Debian system. How I can find this script?

Comment: Notice the timestamps, too: 17:39:48 vs 17:40:25.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I've updated the question

Comment: The user `user` and the directory `/home/user` are mentioned.  This means it's something in this user's configuration that is doing the work.

Comment: My *guess* based on the log entry above is that something in the configuration of Gnome Terminal is trying to show the uptime in some status field, and is trying to do it with the command `sudo -n uptime`. The -n means "non-interactive", which prevents prompting for a password. If a password is required, the command fails with the exact error message you have shown.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Adding `%adm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/uptime` to the `sudoers` file solves the issue. But I'm still have no idea what it is and if it is the right way